# Ridge regression and OLS regression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, regression

Ridge regression differs from OLS regression very slightly. Mathematically, OLS regression uses the formula

[image]

where ridge regression uses the formula

[image]

I wanted to use ridge regression to avoid multicolinearity, but got back very strange results which were substantially worse than simply using regress(). In matlab, to call the function ridge, one must input an X, a Y, and a value for k. Theoretically, if k is set to zero, these equations should be the same; but when both are called back to back in my code, using the same values of X and Y, I receive two very different matrices for B (shown below). Can someone explain why this would happen?

```
b_ridge = ridge(Y_current,X, 0)

    12.4525
    9.0099
    0.2808
    -1.5426
    -1.1107

b_regress = regress(Y_current,X)

    3.5586
    0.8805
    0.1670
    -0.3934
    -0.8526
```

Comment: Is it possible to give us some idea of `Y_current` and `X` are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acording to [`ridge`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/ridge.html) documentation:

> The results are computed after centering and scaling the `x` columns so they have mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

Here's an example using column vectors:

```
>> x = randn(5,1);
>> y = randn(5,1);
>> ridge(y, x, 0)
ans =
  -0.045681220595243
>> regress(y, x)
ans =
  -0.028738686366027
>> regress(y, (x-mean(x))/std(x))
ans =
  -0.045681220595243
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was poking around and you can get the same results as regress by removing the column of ones put into X for a scaling factor and setting the scaling factor input to 0. Thanks again!

      b_regress = regress(Y_current,X);
      b_ridge = ridge(Y_current,X(:,2:5), 0, 0);